# Conversion of a numpy matrix into a single column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let us consider a matrix with shape 3x3 written as a numpy array:

```
np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

The goal is to store the previous vectors in a pandas dataframe with a single column. In the following image is a representation of the objective.

[image]

Comment: In addition, it's not a great idea to store lists in a cell; you're going to complicate your life down the road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame([[i] for i in np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `tolist` on the array as the value in a dictionary.

```
pd.DataFrame({0: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]).tolist()})

           0
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [4, 5, 6]
2  [7, 8, 9]
```

Or without the dictionary

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])[:, None].tolist())

           0
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [4, 5, 6]
2  [7, 8, 9]
```